# LED Wall neutral current problems

Tags: current, neutral

I’m running a film project that involve a huge Led wall.
I have 1000 screens that can pull .6 amp each they are balanced for load on a 400amp 3 phase supply but I’m measuring the same current in the neural as the phases. Is this due to the harmonics it’s causing.
If so should I worry about what it’s doing to the generator power it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's probably harmonic current, to be sure measure the frequency.

Comment: Are the power supplies PFC (power factor corrected)?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I don’t believe they are PFC as they are a totally new product from China. 
When we have them all running I can it’s making the voltage on the generator a little unstable and I’m concerned that It will effect the windings on the generator.